# complete data is not showing on pagination firestore android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an application where I want to use pagination in my recyclerview, I have a nested database and I want to get the data progressively. By scrolling to load 10 items but the problem is after loading 10 items it shows no data. No error nothing simply it does not show the data. I tried this same code with simple databse it is working fine but in my nested database it is not working. please guide me

**VARIABLES**

```
private int limit = 10;
private DocumentSnapshot lastVisible;
private boolean isScrolling = false;
private boolean isLastItemReached = false;
```

COMPLETE CODE

```
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query productsRef =  firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup("room_details");
    Query query = productsRef.orderBy("location", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(limit);

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {


            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot d : task.getResult()) {
                    RoomsDetails obj = d.toObject(RoomsDetails.class);
                    roomsDetails.add(obj);
                }

                roomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);

            RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                        isScrolling = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                    int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();

                    if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached) {
                        isScrolling = false;
                        Query nextQuery = productsRef.orderBy("location", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).startAfter(lastVisible).limit(limit);
                        nextQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> t) {
                                if (t.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : t.getResult()) {
                                        RoomsDetails productModel = d.toObject(RoomsDetails.class);
                                        roomsDetails.add(productModel);
                                    }
                                    roomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    lastVisible = t.getResult().getDocuments().get(t.getResult().size() - 1);

                                    if (t.getResult().size() < limit) {
                                        isLastItemReached = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            };                            recyclerViewRooms.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);


        }
    });
}
```

**COLLECTION GROUP ASC_Index Image**
[image]

**DataBase Structure**
[image]

Comment: Hey again, Vivek. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo please check sir

Comment: Is your second `onComplete` even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo it is not triggering sir

Comment: At least `onScrolled` is called?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sir it is called

Comment: Then most likely `isScrolling && (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount`, returns false, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sir now?

Comment: sir if I am click in the other fragment and return back to that fragment then it is showing the data but when I scroll it throws error i have added above please check

Comment: Do you have enough data in the database so it can be paginated? Are you sure all documents within that collection, are of the same type? I see document with different ID lenghts.

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry sir thay was dummy data i have deleted these files so in my database i have 8 items and my limit is 4 sir

Comment: sir now when app opens for the first it does not showing then i go another fragment then come back this time it is showing the data. what is hapening sir

Comment: If you set the limit to 4, then add at least 20 elements in the database, to see the pagination working. But this will work only if those 4 elements fit into the entire screen.

Comment: in my screen max two items is showing  sir

Comment: Most likely the issue is related to those boolean values, right? So you should step through the debugger and see why those variables do not hold the correct values.

Comment: @AlexMamo sir i changed my xml design and now it is working i was using nested scroll view and some other elements drawerlayout and all i removed them it working now

Comment: Good to hear that ;)

Comment: @AlexMamo hey sir can you please help me problem with this please sir, i am putting question link here

Comment: @AlexMamo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872420/passing-arraylist-of-object-between-fragments-throwing-error-using-safe-args

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Comment: ok sir please check i tried every solution but nothing works.

Comment: i tried viewmodel it is also not working here link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881373/how-to-make-viewmodel-variable-assesible-outside-method-in-android

Comment: @AlexMamo did you check sir??

Comment: Vivek , please post the resolution steps that worked for you as an answer,so others who are facing similar issues can get help.Thankyou.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar it was not the problem of code it was an issue of my xml. I just made some minor changes in my xml.