# Passing arraylist of object between fragments throwing error using safe args

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am working on an application where I need to pass the ArrayList model object to the next fragment but it is throwing an error. i tried many documents but nothing works please guide me why this is happening.I am retrieving data through firebase and want to set this ArrayList on my recyclerview adapter. how can I do that?? please guide me

**CODE FROM FRAGMENT A**

```
   ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> mydatalist = new ArrayList<>();
                HomeFragmentDirections.ActionHomeToSearchDataFragment dr = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeToSearchDataFragment(mydatalist);
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(dr);
```

**CODE FROM FRAGMENT B(RECEIVING FRAGMENT)**

```
 ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> mylist;
    if (getArguments()!=null)
    {

        SearchDataFragmentArgs args = SearchDataFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments());
        mylist = args.getMylist();
        adapter = new SearchRecycleAdapter(mylist, getContext());
        binding.searchDataRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        
    }
```

**MODEL CLASS**

```
public class RecyclerviewModel implements Parcelable {

String name;
String email;
String desc;
String book;
List<String> images;
String uid;
String searching;


public RecyclerviewModel() {
}

public RecyclerviewModel(String name, String email, String desc, String book, List<String> images, String uid,String searching) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.book = book;
    this.images= images;
    this.uid = uid;
    this.searching = searching;
}

protected RecyclerviewModel(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    email = in.readString();
    desc = in.readString();
    book = in.readString();
    images = in.createStringArrayList();
    uid = in.readString();
    searching = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<RecyclerviewModel> CREATOR = new Creator<RecyclerviewModel>() {
    @Override
    public RecyclerviewModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new RecyclerviewModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerviewModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new RecyclerviewModel[size];
    }
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getBook() {
    return book;
}

public void setBook(String book) {
    this.book = book;
}

public List<String> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<String> images) {
    this.images = images;
}


public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}


public String getSearching() {
    return searching;
}

public void setSearching(String searching) {
    this.searching = searching;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeString(email);
    parcel.writeString(desc);
    parcel.writeString(book);
    parcel.writeStringList(images);
    parcel.writeString(uid);
    parcel.writeString(searching);
}
```

}

**Navgraph**
[image]
**ERROR IT IS THROWING**

```
error: incompatible types: ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> cannot be converted to RecyclerviewModel
```

Comment: Why are you extending Arraylist<RecyclerViewModel> in the RecyclerViewModel class?

Comment: I just removed it vivek bhai still it is throwing error

Comment: can i pass the Arraylist<Model> through the safe args bhai tried many documents but nothing works

Comment: basically what I want to do is that I want to pass this Arraylist<Model>  to the next fragment B from frag A so that I can set this arraylist data on the fragment B's recyclerview adapter

Comment: Include the code for the navigation graph in the question where you defines your arguments for the navigation.

Comment: vivek bhai can't we pass without safe args using bundles or something

Comment: @please check i have added tha nav graph

Comment: vivek bhai i have used it it is showing some problem please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881373/how-to-make-viewmodel-variable-assesible-outside-method-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You should create another empty class which extends ArrayList like this:

```
@Parcelize
public class RecyclerModels extends ArrayList<RecyclerViewModels> implements Parcelable
```

Then set the type of the navigation argument to this class.

```
<argument
  android:name="mylist"
  app:argType="your.package.RecyclerModels"/>
```

Your `RecyclerViewModel` should also be `Parcelable`

Comment: it is not working vivek bhai

Comment: Is it still giving the same error

Comment: yes same as before bhai  i read on stack that safe arfs does not  provide support for this kind of data passing

Comment: is not there any other way i am sure vivek bhai you know that

Comment: Well you can use bundles to share data as well and you can even share viewmodels between fragments to pass data.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont know, you are trying to do something like this somewhere:

```
ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> arr=...;
RecyclerviewModel rm=arr;
```

so, check your code again.≈≈

you can use a class and interface to pass the data (its not the best way, but i use that)

```
public class Helper{
public static Sender sender;
interface Sender {
public void Send(Object object);
}
}
```

in fragment 2 (reciever):

```
Helper.sender = new Helper.Sender(){
public void Send(Object ob){
//What it should do on recieve ?
//e.g : RecyclerviewModel r=(RecyclerviewModel)ob;
}
}
```

in fragment 1 (sender):

```
//example:
Helper.sender.Send(RecyclerviewModel);
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: hey is not there is another way

Comment: i use this way.., the idea is saving the data in class and use the interface to send and receive it..., what is the problem ?

Comment: i did not get it completely sorry i am naive